# Is it possible to use one static variable in property that is accessible by both the getter and setter

Tags: vb.net

**Not taking performance into account**, it can be handy to use a static variable inside the getter for a readonly property since:

1. It allows you to save information between get calls
2. The information is only accessible by the property

The problem is that it does not seem to be accessible by the property's setter. Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: if it is readonly it cant have a setter, so `it does not seem to be accessible by the property's setter` doesnt make much sense or I am not understanding the question.

Comment: What I'm asking is to have a normal property, not readonly, with custom a getter and setter. It seems that in order to have a custom getter and setter, you have to have an external variable. What I wanted to figure out was if you could have a variable that is private to the property itself, such as if you put a static variable within the getter of a readonly property.

Answer (score 0):

No, because that does not make sense. You could expose a static value via a read only property, sure. By the very definition of "Static" you cannot assign anything to it, which is the only purpose of the Set method of a property.

Edit: To clarify, you could do something else with the inbound 'value' of Set... but then you aren't really setting the member variable the property exposes anymore, which sounds like you just need a Public Class Sub that does whatever your weird Set would do.